# Render Html/js from server side in Spring

Tags: html, json, spring-boot

Render Html/js from server side in Spring boot .I want that when there is a backend REST Api call .I want to render everything in js but not using jsp .I want to know how to use viewResolver so that I can do it in js using xhr requests and html .
Thanking you in advance ,any help will be extremely helpful

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if i understood your problem correctly but for spring there is a good extension Hateoas to build RESTful APIs. There you can define how to render your output.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/